# Recursively turn all dicts inside a dict into a custom Dict class

Tags: python, class, dictionary, inheritance

Here's a class that returns `None` when a key doesn't exist (as opposed to crashing the entire application) and allows accessing keys like attributes:

```
class Dict(dict):  # a dictionary that returns @None when a key doesn't exist (as opposed to crashing the entire application...) and allows accessing keys like attributes
  def __init__(   self, *args,**kwargs):
    super(Dict,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self.__dict__ = self  # this allows accessing keys like attributes
  def __getitem__(self, key,default=None):
    return dict.get(self, key,default)  # return None if the key exists not
  def __getattribute__(self, attr):  # return None if the attribute exists not
    try:                    return object.__getattribute__(self,attr)
    except AttributeError:  return None
```

You can use it like so:

```
x = Dict({'a':0, 'b':1})
print(x['a'], x.a)
print(x['c'], x.c)
```

The problem is that this doesn't get applied recursively:

```
x = Dict({'a':{'aa':0x00}, 'b':1})
print(x['a'], x.a)
print(x.a['aa'])
print(x.a.aa)  # AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'aa'
```

How can this be fixed.

Comment: You know there is such thing as `defaultdict`, right?

Comment: Have you tried `x = Dict({'a':Dict({'aa':0x00}), 'b':1})`

Comment: "The problem is that this doesn't get applied recursively:" Because you don't implement any recursion. You have to do that yourself. There's no magic here.

Comment: @Dilara Yes, that's want I want to do, but automatically, not by hand

Comment: Do you want dicts with regular syntax like `{'a': 1}` to automatically to become Dicts? I don't think that's possible (unless by some really evil hack). On the other hand, such "tricks" are pretty horrible anyway, and should be avoided.

Comment: @JussiNurminen No, regular syntax shouldn't become a `Dict` automatically. But a manual call like `Dict(x)`, where `x` is a Python `dict`, should recursively turn all Python `dicts` inside `x` to `Dicts`.

Comment: Well, if you want to do that, you need to do it in `Dict.__init__()`. How could Python automatically know that you want to convert regular dicts to Dicts?

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider you requirements. First, you want something that returns `None` for missing keys, i.e. `defaultdict` -like behavior. However in real code, you'll discover that even `defaultdict` is often too much magic. Usually you *want* to know when keys are missing, instead of silently returning `None`, and instead of "crashing the entire application" you can just catch the exception:

```
try:
   di[key]
except KeyError:
   # handle missing key
```

Second, you want attribute access. That is understandable, since writing `di.a` is much nicer than `di['a']` (especially on my Finnish keyboard and many others, where square brackets are behind a modifier key!) However, mixing *both* attribute access and item access (dict-like behavior) into the same object is problematic. For example, consider your `Dict`. What if someone does

```
di = Dict()
di['keys'] = ['C#', 'D']
di.keys()  # TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Now, your object no longer works properly as a dict. Same problem for any other dict method. I guess you could write `__setitem__()` and `__setattribute__()` guards that prevent overwriting dict methods, but it starts to get complicated.

In my opinion, you should decide whether you want item access or attribute access, and not try to implement both. If you want attributes, dataclasses are great (and you can implement `__getattr__()` to return `None` for missing attributes). If you want item access, just use a `defaultdict`.

Comment: Yup, I'm aware of the problem of smushing everything into a single namespace. I guess you just gotta avoid using `keys`, `values`, `items`, etc. as keys, or simply forbid those as keys. But putting `try/except` blocks around *every single dictionary access* surely is madness! You're turning 1 line of code into 4, for no reason! Dataclasses might be nice, haven't tried them yet, thanks for pointing them out.

Comment: Well, usually you create the dicts yourself, so you know precisely what the keys are. In that case there is no need for `try/except`. However if the keys come from an external source, you often simply _have_ to check whether a given key exists. There's no way around it. The `defaultdict` trick seems nice at first, but it doesn't allow you to e.g. differentiate between a nonexistent key and a key that has a value of `None`. Therefore, it can easily become a source of subtle bugs.

Comment: Of course, sometimes `defaultdict` is fine, but it requires some caution. Especially returning those from an API is problematic (IMO) since they can mislead the user.